# Unable to replace characters in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def rmv_spc(lst,a):
        a = str(a)
        for i in lst:
            i = str(i)
            i.replace(a,"")
        return lst
    print(rmv_spc([343, 893, 1948, 3433333, 2346],3))
```

The output is always the same list.

Comment: Hi Anis, what list are expecting?, is the print statement meant to be in the function?

Comment: Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question so others can understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work,

```
def rmv_spc(lst,a):  
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = str(lst[i]).replace(str(a),"")

  return lst 

print(rmv_spc([343, 893, 1948, 3433333, 2346],3))
```

Output -

```
['4', '89', '1948', '4', '246']
```

Your code was successfully replacing the characters from each item in the list, but it wasn't replacing the old item with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `i.replace(a, "")` only returns the replaced string. You need to assign the result back into your list. To do this, you need to edit `lst` with an index `i`:

```
def rmv_spc(lst, a):
    a = str(a)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        x = str(lst[i])
        lst[i] = x.replace(a, "")
    return lst
```

A better way would be to use a list comprehension:

```
def rmv_spc(lst, a):
    a = str(a)
    return [str(x).replace(a, "") for x in lst]
```

---

This is how `replace` works:

```
# Assign x
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> x
'abc'
# Replace 'a' with nothing
>>> x.replace('a','')
'bc'
# That is the result that we wanted, but x is still the same
>>> x
'abc'
# So we need to say that x = that result
>>> x = x.replace('a','')
>>> x
'bc'
```